# How to read a local notification's trigger DateComponents in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

My application is meant to deliver a daily notification with some content specific for that day. I know that iOS can store up to 64 future scheduled notifications, so I'm looking for a way to make sure that tomorrow's notification is always ready to fire, even if the user hasn't opened the app in more than a day.

To that end, in my main ViewModel I have a function that does that, but first it cancels all pending notifications to ensure there are no duplicates. However, this is obviously not the best approach.

So, here's my question: I use the class and function below to list all pending notifications. I can access the trigger, but how do I get the actual date in it, so that I can perform some logical check (e.g. only delete those requests that are 2+ days in the future)?

```swift
class LocalNotificationManager {
    
    static let shared = LocalNotificationManager()
    var notifications = [Notification]()
    let NC = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    
    func listScheduledNotifications() {
        NC.getPendingNotificationRequests { notifications in
            
            for notification in notifications {
                print("Notification [\(notification.identifier)], \(String(describing: notification.trigger))")
                
            }
            print("Pending notifications: [\(notifications.count)]")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample output of this function:

```
Notification [2023-07-28_AB5DD5E7-45F6-47E7-8A98-7670C3C8214F],
Optional(<UNCalendarNotificationTrigger: 0x6000023f8040; 
dateComponents: <NSDateComponents: 0x600002198dd0> {
    Calendar Year: 2023
    Month: 7
    Day: 28
    Hour: 10
    Minute: 15, repeats: NO>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast `notification.trigger` to `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`. This may fail, as not all triggers are based on date components. You should decide what you want to do with the ones not based on date components.

```
if let trigger = notification.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger {
    // check if the next time this notification triggers is within two days
} else {
    // not based on date components...
}
```

As for how you check if check if the next time this notification triggers is within two days, you can use [`nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293473-nextdate) to get a `Date`, and then check if the `Date` is within 2 days.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
if let nextTriggerInstant = calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: trigger, matchingPolicy: .strict) {
    if nextTriggerInstant.timeIntervalSinceNow > 60 * 60 * 48 { // 48 hours
        // delete the notification
    }
}
```

Note that the above checks if `nextTriggerInstant` is within the next 48 hours. If you want a date-based calculation (only looking at the year-month-day components), use [`dateComponents(_:from:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293176-datecomponents).

```
let dateComponentsNow = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
let dateComponentsAtTrigger = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: nextTriggerInstant)
let days = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: dateComponentsNow, to: trigger)
if days > 2 {
    // delete...
}
```